# How to check whether an id is equal to the user's id and conditionally show buttons in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach, react-redux, rxjs

Hey guys I am new to react and currently trying to show 2 buttons based on a condition. I need to check whether the user exists in an array with the user id and show the corresponding button.

This is the json response I am receiving.

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 8, username: "testuser5"}
1: {id: 4, username: "testuser2"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

this is the code I have.

```
const [pending, setPending] = useState([]);

const pendingfun = async function pendingInfo() {
    await axiosInstance.get(url).then((res) => {
        const pending = res.data;
        setPending(pending)
        // console.log(pending)
    })
}

pending.forEach(x => x.id === user.id) ?             
    <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disableElevation                                         
    >
        Save
    </Button> 
    :   <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disableElevation>
             Cancel
        </Button>
```

The problem is when I run this, none of the buttons are showing on the screen. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: useEffect Hook will work here for you. add pending state in dependency array

Comment: I use useEffect to call this function.

Comment: you can use the find method instead of forEeach

Comment: Even that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything, only iteracts over the array. You should use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead to return the correct button:

```
pending.find(x => (x.id !== user.id)) ?             
    <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disableElevation                                         
    >
        Save
    </Button> 
    :   <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disableElevation>
             Cancel
        </Button>
```

Comment: but when I used map, I am getting multiple buttons and sometimes both buttons.

Comment: sry,  I misread. use `find` method, or `some` as well

Comment: I used `find` and `some` but the Save button is showing instead of cancel. it isn't changing.

Comment: but don't you want to show `Save` if id is found?

Comment: Its like if the id is there, I want the cancel button. if its not I want the save button. I'm sorry i need to change the button name from save to add.

Comment: Yes. It works now. was a foolish mistake.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome :) if you find any issue you could consider using `every` method.

Comment: I wasn't aware of all these methods before.

Comment: every will return true if all elements pass in the condition, find will match the first that pass the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
const id1: number = 1;
const id2: number = 1;

// Check if the IDs are the same
const areIdsEqual: boolean = id1 === id2;

console.log(areIdsEqual)
```

Comment: I don't think this code applies to the question asked.